# How to validate form if empty values passed to form fields in Django?

Tags: python, django

Below is the form:

struggling to validate form with sending empty values for some form fields.

[image]

Name and phone were mandatory field. When user type and click submit, All the values should be concatenated and save it in file.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ReviewForm1(forms.Form):
    PRECAUTIONS_CHOICES = (
        ('no', 'No'),
        ('yes', 'Yes')
    )
    UNIT1_CHOICES = (
        ('Very Satisfied', 'Very Satisfied'),
        ('Satisfied', 'Satisfied'),
        ('neutral', 'neutral'),
        ('Unsatisfied', 'Unsatisfied'),
        ('Very Unsatisfied', 'Very Unsatisfied'),
    )
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': 'true'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': 'true'}))
    precautions = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices= PRECAUTIONS_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select())
    unit1_ambience = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices= UNIT1_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select())
    review = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea())

    def clean(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        review = self.cleaned_data.get('review')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        precautions = self.cleaned_data.get('precautions')
        unit1_ambience = self.cleaned_data.get('unit1_ambience')
        expected_string = ''
        options = [name,phone,review,email,precautions,unit1_ambience]
        for option in options:
            if not option:
                continue
            else:
                expected_string = expected_string + option + '\n'

        # concat all with review and then return string
        return expected_string
```

**views.py** snippet

```
@require_POST
@csrf_protect
def revfile_save(request):
   """
   This page processes and saves review file.
   """
   form = ReviewForm1(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        review = form.cleaned_data
   reviewfile_name = "/root/sjfacweb/" + remote.sjfacweb()
   #content writes to timestamped filename
   remote.write_reviewfile(reviewfile_name,False,review)
```

Below is the error I am getting when clicked save:

**local variable 'review' referenced before assignment**

I think form.is_valid() returns false, how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with "empty fields". The rest of that view should be within the `is_valid` block, and you should do something else - ie re-render the template with the invalid form - when the form is not valid.

```
form = ReviewForm1(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    review = form.cleaned_data
    reviewfile_name = "/root/sjfacweb/" + remote.sjfacweb()
    #content writes to timestamped filename
    remote.write_reviewfile(reviewfile_name,False,review)
    return redirect('somewhere')
else:
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

Note though that `clean()` should return the cleaned data as a dict, not a concatenated string; the concatenation should be done somewhere else.